# Can't install oracle client for oracle_cx on mac

Tags: oracle, cx-oracle

Trying to install oracle client for mac for oracle_cx. When I'm trying to install oracle

I'm getting this message:

```
install_ic.sh                                                     
    /Users/ user/Downloads/instantclient_19_8
    Creating dir: /Users/ user/Downloads/instantclient_19_8...
    Copying /Volumes/instantclient-basic-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru files ...
    Using existing dir: /Users/ user/Downloads/instantclient_19_8...
    Copying /Volumes/instantclient-basic-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru files ...
    Using existing dir: /Users/ user/Downloads/instantclient_19_8...
    Copying 1 files ...
    cp: 1/*: No such file or directory
    Using existing dir: /Users/ user/Downloads/instantclient_19_8...
    Copying /Volumes/instantclient-basic-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru files ...
    Using existing dir: /Users/ user/Downloads/instantclient_19_8...
    Copying 2 files ...
    cp: 2/*: No such file or directory
```

So when I'm trying to use cx_oracle after this I'm getting an error:

```
DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#usinginitoracleclient that can initialize oracle client using:

```
import cx_Oracle
import sys
import os

try:
    if sys.platform.startswith("darwin"):
        lib_dir = os.path.join(os.environ.get("HOME"), "Downloads",
                               "instantclient_19_8")
        cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=lib_dir)
    elif sys.platform.startswith("win32"):
        lib_dir=r"C:\oracle\instantclient_19_9"
        cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=lib_dir)
except Exception as err:
    print("Whoops!")
    print(err);
    sys.exit(1);
```

So I pasted

```
lib_dir = os.path.join(os.environ.get("HOME"), "Downloads",
                               "instantclient_19_8")
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=lib_dir)
```

before cursor definition and cx_oracle started work properly.

Comment: For reference that's also mentioned in the cx_Oracle Installation instructions: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#id6